# How do I delete a specific line from text file in C?

Tags: c

Example:

> George 50 40
>   Lime 30 20
>   Karen 10 60

```
do {
    printf("\nInput player name:[1..10] ");
    fgets(name,10,stdin);
}
```

Input name: Lime

Then the text file will be:

> George 50 40
>   Karen 10 60

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 /* C Program Delete a specific Line from a Text File
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fileptr1, *fileptr2;
    char filename[40];
    char ch;
    int delete_line, temp = 1;

    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    //open file in read mode
    fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    ch = getc(fileptr1);
   while (ch != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", ch);
        ch = getc(fileptr1);
    }
    //rewind
    rewind(fileptr1);
    printf(" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:");
    scanf("%d", &delete_line);
    //open new file in write mode
    fileptr2 = fopen("replica.c", "w");
    ch = 'A';
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        ch = getc(fileptr1);
        //except the line to be deleted
        if (temp != delete_line)
        {
            //copy all lines in file replica.c
            putc(ch, fileptr2);
        }
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            temp++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fileptr1);
    fclose(fileptr2);
    remove(filename);
    //rename the file replica.c to original name
    rename("replica.c", filename);
    printf("\n The contents of file after being modified are as follows:\n");
    fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    ch = getc(fileptr1);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", ch);
        ch = getc(fileptr1);
    }
    fclose(fileptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

Reference - http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-delete-line-text-file/

Comment: Will not work for huge files without using tons of disk and time.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you can delete a line,
one simple method is to open two files, one in and one out.

then copy line by line and skip the line you want to delete
after you are done, delete the old file and rename the new one to the old name.

```
fopen()
fgets()
fputs()
rename()
unlink()
```

EDIT: the above solution would work fine with a small file but as by comment it is not suitable for a large file so here comes an alternative solution (GCC C99) which reads in the whole file, finds the name then moves the lines after that line forward in the buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static size_t deleteLine( char*, size_t, const char* );

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char file[] = "yourfile.txt";

  if ( --argc )
  { 
    struct stat st;
    if ( stat( file, &st ) != -1 )
    {
      // open the file in binary format
      FILE* fp = fopen( file, "rb" );
      if ( fp != NULL )
      {
        // allocate memory to hold file
        char* buffer = malloc( st.st_size ); 

        // read the file into a buffer
        if ( fread(buffer, 1, st.st_size, fp) == st.st_size)
        {
          fclose(fp);

          size_t newSize = deleteLine( buffer, st.st_size, argv[1] );

          fp = fopen( file, "wb" );
          if ( fp != NULL )
          {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, newSize, fp);
            fclose(fp);
          }
          else
          {
            perror(file);
          }
        }
        free(buffer);
      }
      else
      {
        perror(file);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      printf( "did not find %s", file );
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

static size_t deleteLine( char* buffer, size_t size, const char* playerName )
{
  // file format assumed to be as specified in the question i.e. name{space}somevalue{space}someothervalue\n
  // find playerName
  char* p = buffer; 
  bool done = false;
  size_t len = strlen(playerName);
  size_t newSize = 0;
  do
  {
    char* q = strchr( p, *playerName ); // look for first letter in playerName
    if ( q != NULL )
    {
      if ( strncmp( q, playerName, len ) == 0 ) // found name?
      {
        size_t lineSize = 1; // include \n already in line size

        // count number of characters the line has.
        for ( char* line = q; *line != '\n'; ++line) 
        {
          ++lineSize;
        }

        // calculate length left after line by subtracting offsets
        size_t restSize = (size_t)((buffer + size) - (q + lineSize));

        // move block with next line forward
        memmove( q, q + lineSize, restSize );

        // calculate new size
        newSize = size - lineSize;
        done = true;
      }
      else
      {
        p = q + 1; // continue search
      }
    }
    else
    {
      puts( "no such name" );
      done = true;
    }
  }
  while (!done);

  return newSize;
}
```

Comment: And if I want to do that on several files of several thousands of lines ? Not a very good solution...

Comment: that is correct, my answer was calibrated after OPs question i.e. some kind of school task with a file that is around 10 lines long, in a real-world problem one would do differently.

Comment: don't you need to `free(buffer)` in `main`?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow yes, seemed to have forgotten that. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In a real world situation, you would need to first order the lines by some criteria and generate, at least, a partial index, i.e. first letter, to, at a minimum, be able to seek to that position before each search. You can stretch that concept to more significant characters in the index, but when you take the index concept to the limit, you end up with the text file ordered by differeent criteria and complex algorithms in a database like manner. If you want to maximize efficiency without programming a database, just order by the first two letters and keep an index of that to seek in as needed

Comment: For several files of several million lines, the first solution is better (faster and simpler), as moving stuff around in memory is just a waste of time.  For removing mulitple lines from one file, the first approach is STILL better, but requires a good index to find the lines to filter out -- read line, test if it should be included or filtered, write line if not filtered.  Moving stuff is only useful if you mmap the file, which has the disadvantage that it is non-atomic.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a file like an array. If we want to delete an element at index i of an array, we shift all elements from i+1 one step towards left and then logically reduce the size of array.

I am applying same princliple on files. In the end ftruncate() is used to reduce the size of file and hence removing the end parts of the file.This code works fine for large files too, as at any time only one byte is being stored in memory.

```
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
/*
 * Description: fdelete() deletes 'bytes' bytes of data from the stream pointed to by fp. 
 *              bytes will be deleted from the CURRENT FILE POSITION.
 *              File must be opened in read + write mode while passing file pointer 
 *              to this function.
 *              File position before calling the function and after the 
 *              function returns will be the same.
 * Return Values: returns 0 on success and errno on failure. Kindly use perror("") 
 *                to print error if non-0 return value returned.
 */
int fdelete(FILE* fp, int bytes) {
    
    // to store each byte/char from file
    char byte;
    long readPos = ftell(fp) + bytes, writePos = ftell(fp), startingPos = writePos;
    // start reading from the position which comes after the bytes to be deleted
    fseek(fp, readPos, SEEK_SET);
    while (fread(&byte, sizeof(byte), 1, fp)) {
        // modify readPos as we have read right now
        readPos = ftell(fp);
        // set file position to writePos as we are going to write now
        fseek(fp, writePos, SEEK_SET);
        
        // if file doesn't have write permission
        if (fwrite(&byte, sizeof(byte), 1, fp) == 0) 
            return errno;
        // modify writePos as we have written right now
        writePos = ftell(fp);
        // set file position for reading
        fseek(fp, readPos, SEEK_SET);
    }

    // truncate file size to remove the unnecessary ending bytes
    ftruncate(fileno(fp), writePos);
    // reset file position to the same position that we got when function was called.
    fseek(fp, startingPos, SEEK_SET); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new file. You can open the original file with `r+` and store its contents into an array (following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44615730/12664847)). Then you can use a for loop to scan the array for the line you want to skip, and delete that line. Then you can overwrite the contents of the file using `fseek(filename,0,SEEK_SET)` (to reset the position indicator of the file) and using a for loop and fprintf to copy the contents from the modified array to the file.
(However, with this method you will need to enter an extra blank line in the last for loop to overwrite the last line of the original file.)