# How to read a .txt file into C array line by line?

Tags: c, arrays

i have a .txt file named `Members.txt` which contain:

```
2
Rebaz salimi 3840221821 0918888888
Hojjat Qolami 2459816431 09177777777
```

i had written a C file to read `Members.txt` into `char w[100];` array like:

```
int main()
{
       int i = 0, line = 5;
       char w[100];
       char f[20];
       char k[15];
       FILE *myfile;
                      myfile = fopen("Members.txt","r");
                      if (myfile== NULL)
                      {
                       printf("can not open file \n");
                       return 1;
                      }

     while(line--){
                   fscanf(myfile,"%s",&w[i]);
                   i++;
                   printf("\n%s", &w[i]);
                  }
                   fclose(myfile);
        return 0;
}
```

but ,i need every newline of`Members.txt` to be saved into different array line by line.

Comment: And what happens instead is ....

Comment: What is the `3` for on the first line of the file?

Comment: @Yunnosch it gaves me ability to save each line in different array to process data much more easier later on!

Comment: @alk i had searched many times but no one gaves me for storing each line in different array

Comment: @WeatherVane number of peoples stored in this file which suppose to be 2 in this case!

Comment: So you might like to extend your search query to [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+read+a+.txt+file+into+C+array+line+by+line+into+a+2D+array).

Comment: So why are you ignoring that and using a hard coded loop of 5? Which will try to use the `3` as the first data line then the next two lines, and then there aren't any more.

Comment: Did you notice your code doesn't read the entire line even into the same buffer w?

Comment: @WeatherVane i know but my issue is to reading next line in txt file into new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution if you want to read the file and store inside array, You cannot store inside array, but you can store inside structure of array. Here I make you can access 100 lines of text file. Here is the code anyway:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Use Structure to store more than one data type
//Since your file not only consist of string, it also have int
struct members
{
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    long long int c;
    long long int d;
};
//Here I make 100 line so that you can read 100 line of text file
struct members cur_member[100];

int main(void) {
    FILE *myfile = fopen("Members.txt", "r");
    if (myfile == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        //Check for number of line
            char ch;
            int count = 0;
        do
        {
        ch = fgetc(myfile);
        if (ch == '\n') count++;
        } while (ch != EOF);
        rewind(myfile);

        //Since you put 2 earlier in the member.txt we need to dump it
        //so that it wont affect the scanning process
        int temp;
        fscanf(myfile, "%d", &temp);
        printf("%d\n", temp);
        //Now scan all the line inside the text
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            fscanf(myfile, "%s %s %lld %lld\n", cur_member[i].a, cur_member[i].b, &cur_member[i].c, &cur_member[i].d);
            printf("%s %s %lld %lld\n", cur_member[i].a, cur_member[i].b, cur_member[i].c, cur_member[i].d);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
2
Rebaz salimi 3840221821 918888888
Hojjat Qolami 2459816431 9177777777
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This program will read your current file and I just print it, to show it works. You can access the information and edit the file. 
Thats all..

Comment: `char ch;`-->> `int ch;`

Comment: @Joes Lie you got  these errors:                                                    
 1.error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode|               2. error: expected declaration or statement at end of input|

Comment: How about put the `int i` outside the for loop as updated code. I just update the code test if it work..

Comment: Although this code works for some sample input, it is fragile in that unexpected input would not get detected and cause undefined behavior.  If would also fail with select valid input - although this is OK for learner code.