# how can i delete a whole line containing a string provided by the user in a file

Tags: c

> i need to remove the whole line containing the string a user
>   inserted,i'm having a hard time figuring out how i can delete this
>   line here's is what i tied so far.

for example if **u.txt** contains:
1 hello world
2 where are you
*** user input: you***
***u.txt*** now contains
1.hello world

```
    #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
    FILE *tr1, *tr2;
    char *p;
    char chr;
    char scanner [10];
    int t = 1;
    int sc;
    tr1 = fopen("u.txt", "r");
    chr = getc(tr1);
    while (chr != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", chr);
        chr = getc(tr1);
    }  
      printf("input your word to search:");
      scanf("%s",scanner);
      rewind(tr1);
      tr2 = fopen("replica.txt", "w");
      chr = 'A';

      while (chr != EOF)
      {
       //expect the line to be deleted
        sc= strstr(chr,scanner);
        if (!sc)
        {
           //copy all lines in file replica.txt
           putc(chr, tr2);
        }

      fclose(tr1);
      fclose(tr2);
      remove("u.txt");
      rename("replica.txt", "u.txt");
      tr1 = fopen("u.txt", "r");
      chr = getc(tr1);
       while (chr != EOF)
      {
               printf("%c", chr);
               chr = getc(tr1);
     }
     fclose(tr1);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can *replace* text in a file, provided the new text is smaller or equal to the original text.  To delete text in a file, write all the original text to a new file, except for the deleted text.

Comment: As a beginner, you should decide if you are programming in C or C++.  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` and the `std::fstream` classes;  The C language doesn't.  Adjust your language tags as appropriate (looks like you are programming in C, not C++).

Comment: Try and focus on the problem in your question, especially the title. It doesn't matter if you're new, or inexperienced or whatever. Try and focus on the nature of the problem and how we can help you.

Comment: Are you writing the equivalent of `grep -v`?

Comment: that what i'm trying to do but seems not clear to me,could you plz write simple pseudo for that? @thomas matthews

Comment: my bad,I messed up with the tags i'm doing c ,@Thomas Matthews

Comment: yeah ,exactly @tadman

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a specific line from text file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716785/how-do-i-delete-a-specific-line-from-text-file-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You are making things difficult on yourself by using *character-oriented* input with `fgetc()` with operations that call for *line-oriented* input and output. Moreover, in your approach, you would delete every line in the file containing words where `you` is a lesser-included substring like:

- "you", "your", "you're", "yourself", "you've", etc...

For a simplistic way of ensuring your don't remove lines unless they contain the word `"you"`, you can simply check to ensure the character *before* and *after* the word is *whitespace*. You can use the `isspace()` macro provided in `ctype.h` to simplify the checks.

When you are faced with a *line-oriented* problem use *line-oriented* input and output functions, such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` for input and `puts()` or `fputs()` for output. The only additional caveat is that *line-oriented* input functions read and include the trailing `'\n'` in the buffers they fill. Just remove where necessary by overwriting the trailing `'\n'` with the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` (or simply `0`).

Using a *line-oriented* approach will greatly simplify your task and provide a convenient way write the lines you keep to your output file in a single call rather than looping character-by-character. Using a character-oriented approach is not wrong, and it's not inherently slower than a line-oriented approach -- it's just less convenient. *Match the tool to the job.*

The following example reads `"u.txt"` and writes `"v.txt"` with the unwanted lines removed while preserving lines where the word is a lesser-included substring of the word being sought. (the `rename()` and `remove()` are left to you as there is nothing wrong with that part of your existing code)

Simply using a fixed buffer of sufficient size is the easiest way to do line-oriented input. You will generally know what the largest anticipated line is, just use a buffer that is more than sufficient to handle it (*don't skimp!*). Most lines are no more than 80-120 characters long. A fixed array of 1024-characters is more than sufficient. Just declare an array to use as a buffer to hold each line read, e.g.:

```
#define MAXW   32       /* max chars in word to find */
#define MAXC 1024       /* max chars for input buffer */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC],         /* buffer to hold each line */
        word[MAXW];         /* user input to find/delete line */
    size_t wordlen = 0;     /* length of user input */
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;        /* infile & outfile pointers */
```

You can validate that sufficient arguments were provided on the command line for the input and output filenames and then open and validate each of your files, e.g.

```
    if (argc < 3) { /* validate at least 2 program arguments given */
        printf ("usage: %s infile outfile\n", strrchr (argv[0], '/') + 1);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(ifp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {    /* open/validate open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-ifp");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(ofp = fopen (argv[2], "w"))) {    /* open/validate open for writing */
        perror ("fopen-ofp");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now just take the input from the user and remove the trailing `'\n'`. Using `strcspn` you can get both the length of the user-input while overwriting the trailing `'\n'` in a single call. See: [man 3 strspn](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html), e.g.

```
    fputs ("enter word to find: ", stdout); /* prompt for input */
    fflush (stdout);                        /* optional (but recommended) */

    if (!fgets (word, MAXW, stdin)) {       /* read/validate word to find */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
        return 1;
    }

    /* get wordlen, trim trailing \n from find */ 
    word[(wordlen = strcspn (word, "\n"))] = 0;
```

Now simply read a line-at-a-time and search for `word` within the line and validate is it a whole word and not a part of a larger word. Write all lines that don't contain `word` alone to your output file:

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, ifp)) {    /* read each line */
        char *p = strstr (buf, word);   /* search for word */
        if (!p ||                                       /* word not in line */
            (p != buf && !isspace (*(p - 1))) ||        /* text before */
            (!isspace (p[wordlen]) && p[wordlen] != 0)) /* text after */
            fputs (buf, ofp);           /* write line to output file */
    }
```

(**note:** the `isspace()` macro from checking whether a character is *whitespace* is provided in the header `ctype.h`)

Close both files and aside from your `remove()` and `rename()` you are done. But, **note** you should always validate `fclose()` after a *write* to ensure you catch any errors associated with flushing the file stream on close that would not otherwise be caught by validating each write individually, e.g.

```
    if (fclose (ofp) == EOF) {      /* validate EVERY close-after-write */
        perror ("fclose-ofp");
        remove (argv[2]);
    }

    fclose (ifp);   /* close input file */
}
```

Add the required header files and you have a working example. You can put the example to use as follows:

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/u.txt
hello world
how are you
show yourself
you're missing
```

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/filermline dat/u.txt dat/v.txt
enter word to find: you
```

**Resulting Output File**

```
$ cat dat/v.txt
hello world
show yourself
you're missing
```

Look things over and compare the line-oriented approach to your use of the character-oriented use of `fgetc()`. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Does `isspace()` match punctuation? What about lines like `how are you?` ?

Comment: `isspace()` matches *whitespace* (space, tab, newline, carriage-return, vertical-tab, etc..). How are you? would not being deleted. You can add `ispunct()` as a test to match punctuation. That is why we noted that this simplistic approach only matched the word surrounded by whitespace. You can build on to the example to handle punctuation easily, but then you will have to distinguish between `"you?"` and `"you're"`, etc.. At that point a manual test of allowable characters in a `switch` may be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You're not giving any value to `chr`, it is always `A` at least for the first loop. Is there any lines of code missed? I suggest you checking every line until you find an `EOL` saving it in a string. Then call `strstr()` with it and if the result is NULL you simply copy it into another file.
If keeping it in the same file is  necessary it Will be more dificult, because you got to save a pointer to the start of each line. If this line youre studying is actually one that has to be erased, you got to recopy each following line from this pointer. It is way harder this way.

Good luck!

PS: Maybe this can help, not sure: [How do I delete a specific line from text file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716785/how-do-i-delete-a-specific-line-from-text-file-in-c)